# Python os.walk return code

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

In my application I attempt to walk a set fo directories looking for certain files.

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path_to_network_share):
    print(filenames)
    break
```

The actual attempt to walkt the folders is done by calling **os.walk**. However, even if there is no connection to the network share, **os.walk** will not return an error. How can I catch the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that we can supply a function as an optional argument ('onerror') and that will receive an instance of OSError in return:

```
import os

def walk_error(os_error):
    return(os_error) # [WinError 53] The network path was not found: '\\\\path\\dir\\'

for file in os.walk('\\\\path\\dir\\', onerror=walk_error):
    print(file)
```